# UWP Prevent Exception Output/Debug, Bluetooth Identify and Naming Conventions

Tags: c#, exception, uwp, bluetooth-lowenergy, naming-conventions

I have three small problems.

1. I working on a project, where I need to use Bluetooth. Unfortunately to its async working, there are sometimes thrown some exception, because the device is not ready yet. There is no indicator for that, so I cant prevent the exception from happening. 
   Now is there a way to prevent the exceptions to make an output to the console. Of course I catch them, but I always have the message

> "Exception thrown: "System.Exception" in
>   System.Private.CoreLib.ni.dll"

It is a ElementNotFound Exception, if this helps.

2. Any ideas how to identify a Bluetooth device, other then by its name. I have only the deviceInformation of the device, not the BluetoothLEDevice Object itself. This would contain the manufactory_ID.
3. What are the Naming Conventions in UWP, I wasn't able to find some. Are they the same, as in C# or what should I think about?

Thank you

Marcel

Comment: Without the exception in the output console, then how to know the device is not ready from the app? Did the exception only appeared when you debug? If in that case why you need prevent it? Could you please provide a [mcve] for testing on our side?